# Form transition and data refresh

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with a button and when I push it, it opens another form. When I close this second form I need to refresh the first form.

So I need to insert the first form name in a global variable to access the form name from the second form to refresh the first form.

I tried create this:

```
global formname as form

formname = activeform.name
```

but I receive an error saying: The option is read only.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: The original title said 'access' so I'll go with that unless the OP corrects it.

Comment: This is MS Access VBA.

Comment: 'Global' has been superseded by 'Public'.

Comment: Globally declared variables can lose their state in the case of an unhandled error or stopping execution.  An approach that doesn't rely on global variables would be preferable.

Answer (score 3):

On the `Click` event of the button you can pass the name of the form as the `OpenArgs` property of `DoCmd.OpenForm`.

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmStaff", , , , , , Me.Name

End Sub
```

On the `Close` event of the second form you can check this (string) value:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
    If Me.OpenArgs <> "" Then
        'MsgBox Me.OpenArgs
        Forms(Me.OpenArgs).Refresh  'or .Requery
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just go into the VBA code behind and refresh it with the close sub?  I don't understand the need for a global variable to be passed between the forms - You should be able to just do something like this in your second form:

```
Private Sub Form_Close()
     Form_YourFormHere.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use this approach, try this in the first form's module:

```
Public formname as Form

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Set formname = Me
End Sub
```

or

```
Public formname as String

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    formname = Me.name
End Sub
```

A form is an object type, and can only be assigned to a variable using a Set statement, otherwise VBA will think that you are trying to assign the value of the object to the variable.

You said that you wanted the form *name*, however your variable was a Form type, not a String.  The first code snippet will achieve the result you *appeared* to be trying to achieve, and the second will achieve the result you *said* you wanted to achieve.

A different approach would probably be better and more reliable, though.